# Hugo Failed to Unmashal YAML: Mapping Value issue

Tags: themes, hugo

Run hugo --gc --minify -b
4
Error: "/home/runner/work/TTS/TTS/themes/hugo-theme-stack/config.yaml:146:1": failed to unmarshal YAML: yaml: line 146: mapping values are not allowed in this contex

So I am trying, and failing, to get a theme installed on my blog. I have gotten through a few of the errors and were able to suss out what the issue was. The above one is the current one and I am having a time trying to figure out whats wrong.

The line called into question is:

```
cusdis:     
            host:
            id:
```

These are left blank as I dont know what they want there and usually leaving something blank never impacted me before. What could the issue be?

Comment: Are you sure you need so many spaces? Shouldn't this be 2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the [`CaiJimmy/hugo-theme-stack`](https://github.com/CaiJimmy/hugo-theme-stack).

There is a comments platform called [Cusdis](https://cusdis.com/), and that Hugo theme seems to have support for it, so those fields there are for configuring your Cusdis account.

If you're using it, then you need to create an account over there, and then go back to your config and fill those values in.

If you're not using any comments at allI would suggest to omit that config, e.g. comment out those lines, or just remove them altogether. Something like below.

```yaml
    comments:
        enabled: false
#        provider: disqus

#        disqusjs:
#            shortname:
#            apiUrl:
#            apiKey:
#            admin:
#            adminLabel:
#        ...
```